# Enable or Disable Textbox based on ComboBox value of DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `DataGridView` with one `ComboBox` column and one `TextBox` Column created dynamically as follows

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dcColor = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
dcColor.HeaderText = "Color";
dcColor.Items.Add("Red");
dcColor.Items.Add("Green");

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dcValue = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
dcValue.HeaderText = "Value";

DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, dcColor);
DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, dcValue);
```

Now if the user selects "Red" item in the ComboBox, then the corresponding TextBox cell should be disabled and should be shown in grey color.
If the user selects "Green" item then the corresponding TextBox cell should be enabled.

Also how can we ensure that the user enters data when Green is selected before closing of the datagridview form.

Comment: How can i use EditingControlShowing event which can capture both values/properties of TextBox and ComboBox and implement the as mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works on selection of item in the ComboBox

```
private void _DataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as DataGridView).SelectedCells[0].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxCell))
    {
        if ((e.Control as ComboBox) != null)
        {
            (e.Control as ComboBox).SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
            (e.Control as ComboBox).SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
    }
}

private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString() == "Red")
    {
        _DataGridView.Rows[_DataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
    }
    else 
    { 
        _DataGridView.Rows[_DataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].ReadOnly = false;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the DataGridView's CellValueChanged-Event, to check if any cell value changed. That works the same for all column types wheter a TextBoxColumn or a ComboBoxColumn.

Check for the correct column, in your example the color column is inserted on position 0.
Set the other columns, in your example on index 1 to read only when "Red" is selected.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) {
        bool disable = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "Red";
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].ReadOnly = disable;
    }
}
```

The answer to your second question is to use the Form's FormClosing-Event and validate rows in there. You can cancel the close request by setting `e.Cancel = true` if data wouldn't be correct.